# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I have a problem with `formtastic-bootstrap`.

The `semantic_form_for` catches the following exception:

> undefined
>   method'request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_request_path' for  <#:0xb3580fe4>.

Has anyone ever had such a problem? Or does anyone know the solution?

Comment: is `semdantic_form_for` a typo only on here, or in your main code too?

Comment: As Jules said, formtatic uses `semantic_form_for`